# "Place Order" button not working - no error - no request

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have a clean Magento 2.3.4 setup.
When checking out with a product in the basket, nothing happens when I click on the "Place Order" button. No error is displayed, no console.log, no XHR request fired.

Does anyone have a hint how to debug or solve this?

You can test it here:
https://clean.steelman24-dev.powered-by-rackspeed.de/

[image]

Comment: Its working https://prnt.sc/rtxbge

Comment: Okay, strange. I tried another browser and it is working. After disabling all extensions and clearing all cookies and caches, it is still not working. So something seems to be wrong with my Chrome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place order is working on your test site https://prnt.sc/rtxbge